# Azure Application Insights AAD authentication not supported when debbuging with Visual Studio

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-application-insights

I have my ASP.Net 6 Web API project in Visual studio connected to Application insights in Azure. My Application Insights are configured to use AAD authentication (local authentication disabled).
I have signed in Visual Studio via account with "Monitor telemetry publisher" role assigned. In Fiddler, I can see that telemtery is sent to AI but it fails with 400 HTTP status code and message "Authorization not supported". Telemetry is sent to v2.0 track and as I found in Microsoft Docs, v2.0 track doesn't support AAD authentication, v2.1 track does.
Is there any way to force the telemetry beeing sent to v2.1 track? (Ovbiously, missing AI telemetry is my problem)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct!
Based on the [***`MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-ad-authentication?tabs=net#ingestion-http-errors)

> **"v2/track" does not support Azure AD. When the SDK is correctly
> configured, telemetry will be sent to "v2.1/track"**

***Currently, Azure AD authentication for Application Insights is in Preview***.

So as you are using make sure that you have correctly configured the SDK because there is no way to force the telemetry sent to v2.1 directly, without configured the SDK manually.

Also you can try the same with `.net5` as it is in preview. Once it will be Generally available you can try with `.net6`.

Please refer this [***GitHub issue***](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2190) for more information.

Comment: Ajay thanks for your answer, maybe I'm blind, but I can't see where or how to configure SDK. I use DefaultCredentials in my telemetry client, what else do I have to configure?